# How can I use Volatility3 plugins via a Python script?

Tags: python, volatility

Usually when using **Volatility3**'s plugins via a python script, I can just execute:
`os.system("python3 vol.py -f image.raw windows.imageinfo")`
But how can I get the same result using **Volatility3** as a library, without executing shell commands?
I've looked it up in **Volatility3**'s documentation, but I couldn't find a practical implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
python vol.py -f image.raw windows.info.Info
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).